How to fix Java Swing PrinterJob print being off the page
I have this GUI that I'd like to print in half a letter sheet of paper:
However when printing with this code on the "Confirm print GUI":
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
        

        job.setPrintable(impresionpanel, format);

        if (job.printDialog()) {
            try {
                job.print();
                this.dispose();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error en la impresión.");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "La impresión se canceló.");
        }
       

And this one in the panel that is being printed:
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
if (pageIndex == 0) {
            Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            graphics2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
            printAll(graphics2d);

            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        } else {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
}

The resulting PDF (for testing purposes) turns out like this:
I know there's a sizeableArea attribute in Pageformat Paper, but I didn't play around with it since I feared having nothing to do with what I want to do. Thanks in advance.
I tried changing the size and aspect ratio of the JPanel, but it always gave me the same output.
Changing the second bit of code to:
if (pageIndex == 0) {
            Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            graphics2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
            printAll(graphics);

            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        } else {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

Results in the same thing.

So, you're probably going to need to do some black magic hacking.  The core idea is, you start by creating a new instance of the component, off screen.  You fill it with the data from the on screen version.  You then set its size to match the page width and trigger a layout (probably directly via doLayout), if that fails, make a container panel with a fixed size and place the offscreen component onto it.  At this point, you're kind of ready to print it.  This is one of the mean reasons I don't print components and instead, either roll the Graphics output myself or use JasperReports

For example

Thanks, I'll try that. Every day that passes I'm more and more convinced that printers were created by the devil to laugh at us lol everything around them always is so obscure and complicated.

The Java Tutorials: Printing

I already checked that lol, anyways @MadProgrammer 's solution worked. Thank you very much!
